# I fail to pass custom vars with laravel-sendgrid-driver

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

I add sendgrid support with https://github.com/s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver
in my laravel 8 but I have problems with adding custom perameters. I do in control :

```
    public function banUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = $request->user_id;
        $bannedUser = User::find($user_id);
        if ($bannedUser === null) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'User # "' . $request->user_id . '" not found!'],
                HTTP_RESPONSE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        $site_home_url          = config('app.url');
        $bannedUser->ban_reason = $request->ban_reason;
        if(empty($bannedUser->ban_reason)) {
            $bannedUser->ban_reason= 'Ban em all';
        }
        $bannedUser->status     = false;
        $bannedUser->updated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
        $support_signature                          = config('app.support_signature', '');

        try {
            $bannedUser->save();
            $additiveVars= [ // Additive Vars I want to see in my email view
                'site_home_url'            => $site_home_url,
                'to_user_email'            => $bannedUser->email,
                'to_username'              => $bannedUser->full_name,
                'ban_reason'               => $bannedUser->ban_reason,
                'support_signature'        => $support_signature,
            ];
            $site_name= config('app.APP_NAME');
            $subject= 'Your account at ' . $site_name . ' was banned ';

            \Mail
                ::to($bannedUser->email)
                ->send( new SendgridMail( 'emails/user_was_baned', $bannedUser->email, [], $subject , $additiveVars ) )
//                ->embedData( // if to uncomment these lines it does not work anyway
//                    ['custom_args'=>$additiveVars]
//                );

    }
```

I created custom email objects : /app/Mail/SendgridMail.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Sichikawa\LaravelSendgridDriver\SendGrid;

class SendgridMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    use SendGrid;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    private  $m_view_name;
    private  $m_to_email_address;
    private  $m_ccEmailAddressList;
    private  $m_subject_text;
    private  $m_additiveVars;
    private  $m_attachFiles;

    public function __construct( string $view_name, string $to, array $cc= [], string $subject= '', array $additiveVars= [], array $attachFiles= [] )
    {
        $this->m_view_name= $view_name;
        $this->m_to_email_address= $to;
        $this->m_ccEmailAddressList= $cc;
        }
        $this->m_subject_text= $subject;


        $additiveVars['site_home_url']      = \Config::get('app.url');
        $additiveVars['site_name']          = \Config::get('app.name');
        $additiveVars['mail_from_address']  = \Config::get('app.MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS');
        $additiveVars['mail_from_name']     = \Config::get('app.MAIL_FROM_NAME');
        if ( $this->m_is_debug ) {
            echo '<pre>$additiveVars::' . print_r($additiveVars, true) . '</pre>';
        }
        $this->m_additiveVars= $additiveVars;
        $this->m_attachFiles= $attachFiles;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build( )
    {
        \Log::info(  varDump($this->m_additiveVars, ' -1 build $this->m_additiveVars::') );  // I check list of Additive Vars as I expect 
        $mailObject= $this
            ->view( $this->m_view_name )
            ->subject( $this->m_subject_text )
            ->to( [$this->m_to_email_address] )
            ->cc( $this->m_ccEmailAddressList )
            ->with( $this->m_additiveVars )  // I send list of Additive Vars as into view
            ->sendgrid( $this->m_additiveVars );

        foreach( $this->m_attachFiles as $next_attach_file) {
            if ( file_exists($next_attach_file) ) {
                $mailObject->attach($next_attach_file);
            }
        }
        return $mailObject;

    }
}
```

and resources/views/emails/user_was_baned.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <h4 class="email_title">
        Hello, {{ $to_username }}
    </h4>

    <p class="email_title">You were baned at <a href="{{ $site_home_url }}" target="_blank" class="a_link">{{ $site_name }}</a> site !</p>

    <p class="email_subtitle">Now you can not login under your credentials :<br>
        User's email : {{ $to_user_email }}<br>
        Ban reason : {{ $ban_reason }}
    </p>

    <p class="email_footer">{!! $support_signature !!}</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I got errors like:

`{"message":"User \"29\" not banned : Client error:` POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Additional property site_name is not allowed.\",\"field\":\"site_name\",\"help\":null},{\"message\":\"Addit (truncated...)\n"}`
OR:
`{"message":"User \"29\" not banned : Client error:` POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Additional property mail_from_address is not allowed.\",\"field\":\"mail_from_address\",\"help\":null},{ (truncated...)\n"}`

OR:
`{"message":"User \"29\" not banned : Client error:` POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Additional property to_user_email is not allowed.\",\"field\":\"to_user_email\",\"help\":null},{\"message (truncated...)\n"}`
OR:
`{"message":"User \"29\" not banned : Client error:` POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Additional property site_home_url is not allowed.\",\"field\":\"site_home_url\",\"help\":null},{\"message (truncated...)\n"}`

OR:
`{"message":"User \"29\" not banned : Client error:` POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send`resulted in a`400 Bad Request`response:\n{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"Additional property to_user_email is not allowed.\",\"field\":\"to_user_email\",\"help\":null},{\"message (truncated...)\n"}`
But any of these eorrors is different and looks like any next request raise error with different(next)
var in template.

Why error and how can it be fixed ?

```
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver": "^3.0",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add another package. You can just use SMTP. This would have the benefit that you can just follow the Laravel docs aswell. To setup the SendGrid SMTP configuration this should be added/updated in your `.env` file:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
# MAIL_DRIVER=smtp # for laravel < 7
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=apikey
MAIL_PASSWORD=sendgrid_api_key
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_NAME="John Smith"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
```

Comment: Do you mean that I need to remove laravel-sendgrid-driver and with connection example 
you provided above I need to create a command like:
php artisan make:mail OrderShipped
as written here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail ?
How have I to fill config/mail.php file?


I used laravel-sendgrid-driver in laravel 5.7 app and found it usefull...
But is it differently in laravel 8.12 ?

Comment: You don't need to change anything in config/mail.php. Just make sure your .env has the keyd above set correctly. And yes you can use the default a Laravel Mailables.